# jQuery .focus (on field X) causes .blur (on field X) to get invoked

Tags: jquery, focus, blur

Does anyone know why the jQuery .focus function would cause an onblur event to get called.  The reason I ask is because in my JavaScript custom psuedo class, I am calling this.

```
jQuery(thisTemp.Elements.TxtSampleId).blur(Function.createDelegate(thisTemp,     
    thisTemp.PreAccessioningLoad));
```

But inside of the success JavaScript function (in this same class) for my AJAX call to my WCF service, I have this code.  The *.focus line is causing another instance of my delegate above to get called.  I can prove this by commenting it out.  With the line, my alert gets called twice.  Without it, my alert only gets called once.

```
PreAccessioningLoadSuccess: function(quickDataEntryObject) {

    var val = jQuery(this.Elements.TxtSampleId).val().replace(/^\s\s*/, "").replace(/\s\s*$/, "");
    var intRegex = /^\d{1,10}$/;
    if (!intRegex.test(val)) {
        jQuery(this.Elements.SampleIdAjaxValidate).html("<span style='color:red'>Sample Id must contain between 1 and 10 digits</span>");
        jQuery(this.Elements.TxtSampleId).focus();
        jQuery(this.Elements.ImageAjaxSpinner).css("visibility", "hidden");
        alert("this alert gets called twice when .focus() function called ???");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        jQuery(this.Elements.SampleIdAjaxValidate).html("");  // clear AJAX validation
    }
```

...

Why would that happen?

============
**Here is my delegate event per the request:**

```
PreAccessioningLoad: function(sender) {

    if (this.Elements.TxtSampleId.value != "") {

        var service = new Acu.LIMS.UI.Web.WCFServices.Accessioning.QuickDataEntryService();
        jQuery(this.Elements.ImageAjaxSpinner).css("visibility", "visible");
        service.PreAccessioningLoad(this.Elements.TxtSampleId.value, Function.createDelegate(this, this.PreAccessioningLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.PreAccessioningLoadError));
    }
    return false;  //prevent page postback
},
```

=========================================
Adding my source code:

<asp:TextBox id="TxtSampleId" runat="server" class="LIMSInputField" onfocus="Change(this, event)" onblur="Change(this, event)"/>

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Change(obj, evt) {
        if (evt.type == "focus") {
            obj.style.borderColor = "black";
            obj.style.backgroundColor = "#90EE90";  // light green on focus
        }
        else if (evt.type == "blur") {
            obj.style.borderColor = "white";
            obj.style.backgroundColor = "#7AC5CD";  // light blue on blur
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Um can you please post the event attachment code as well? It looks like this is an incomplete picture.

Comment: off the top of my head -- something is receiving focus during your event handler, causing blur to trigger. haven't had time to go thru your code though, and there's enough missing bits I'm not sure I can.

Comment: Remember, I'm calling Microsoft's ASP.NET Ajax "Function.createDelegate", not jQuery's.  Maybe there's a conflict.  I know jQuery implicitly does callbacks/delegates in their code almost everywhere, but in this situation, how would I get this to work?  The event function is returning false, so nothing else is happening except for that block of code.  We may have to contact the jQuery team on this one.

jQuery(thisTemp.Elements.TxtSampleId).blur(Function.createDelegate(thisTemp, thisTemp.PreAccessioningLoad));

Comment: If you'd like, I can put my code on a live URL and you can debug it.  I am scared to debug delegates.  Haha!  There might be a phobia for that sort of thing.

Comment: I added my source code.  You'll notice that I have a blur event hard coded on the input field, but that is a separate blur event from the one I added via my JavaScript class.  If you really want to reproduce, I'll try to mock something up when I get time.  I will make sure to give you a huge badge if you figure this monster out!  (although I don't know how to give badges)

Comment: I'm also using Script Manager... I do a bunch of stuff in my code behind.  Not sure if that makes a difference.  I'm binding my controls via a ManagedControl, and dynamically adding my javascript file using the ScriptReference object.  The service call is calling a WCF service, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: And it's really not a big deal we figure this out.  I got around the issue.  So don't waste your time unless you feel the need/challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the issue is that the alert fires the blur (as it is now receiving the focus):

```
alert("this alert gets called twice when .focus() function called ???");
```

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/on50g7cr/2/

If you tab to the "focuser" button and then click "click me!" you'll see that the blur event is fired twice (once for losing focus to the "click me" button and then again for losing focus to the alert window).

Comment: I don't work for that company anymore, so I don't have a way to test my code.  So I'll take your word for it with the fiddle.  Nice work!